# How to prevent controller reloading when using ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

In this example, using ng-switch, I'm able to switch between different views.
Each view is assigned a controller.

I've put a quick sample online here : http://jsfiddle.net/FBHjZ/1/

It looks like the controller is reinstanciated everytime I switch views :
If you enter a val in the input field, go to home and switch back to settings, the value is lost.

How can I prevent this? 
Basically, what I want is to keep state from previous views when I switch between views.

Comment: If you're really interested in maintaining the state of them, why not just use ng-show and ng-hide to toggle their visibility? You could also use a custom directive to template/control your views, which would allow two way binding between the directive and it's host page, persisting the data.

Comment: Thx blesh, that's what I was looking for. Another question, is there an event I can listen to when an element is shown? (then calling a method on the controller)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way of preventing the existing `ngSwitch` from re-instantiating controllers and re-creating a new scope. As noted in the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch) this directive is creating a new scope and actually creates / destroys corresponding DOM elements.

If you goal is to preserve state just put it in one of the parent scopes, check this jsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/FBHjZ/2/

An alternative approach is to use a service for the shared model.

Comment: Hmm I see. So I'll use the ng-show/ng-hide solution from blesh for now because I want to avoir redrawing the screen each time. But your solution also works yep.

Comment: Yeh, ng-show/ng-hide works well for small portions of the screen. With bigger DOM fragments it might be better to use ngSwitch (as it is adding / removing DOM elements, so the whole DOM tree is lighter). All depends on the use-case but since you've asked about the ngSwitch :-)

Comment: Yup, but getting back to the previous state can become difficult to handle. Is there a way to keep the previous scope of an element and re-injecting it instead of creating a new one? My application is made of several tabs and subtabs and saving the state of each tab in a service seems difficult to manage

Comment: In this case put your state in one of the parent scopes as in the jsFiddle attached to the response. This is like "preserving the state"